# Python: generating a continuous distribution (type Maxwell-Boltzmann) to generate random values

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I want to generate a continuous distribution (type Maxwell-Boltzmann) with Python. I mean, I want to create the distribution in order to generate random values.

This link kinda helps:

[Create a continuous distribution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676710/create-a-continuous-distribution-in-python)

I don't have idea where to start, I know the analytical function that generates the distribution but I don't know how to implement that. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: SciPy is your best friend http://www.johndcook.com/distributions_scipy.html

Comment: scipy has a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution built-in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html  Have you seen this, and does it do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't know the built-in function. Thanks a lot, that's what I need @tom10.

Comment: OK, I'll write this as an answer, so people will know that this question is answered and can comment, vote, edit, etc.

Answer (score 6):

scipy has a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution built-in, [`maxwell`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html), and its `pdf` method will give you the probability density function.